# calling class method of another javascript in query

Tags: javascript, jquery

The error is:

> ReferenceError: $portal is not defined $portal.user = {

i am writing whole new thing with Jquery and normal javascript.(this is my first web project still learning.)

I am trying to execute $portal.user.init() function from Jquery document ready function, it is not executing.

I may be missing something, could any one please help, how i should call above method from Jquery & concept behind it.

here is my jQuery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                // Initiate portal.. 
                $portal.user.init(<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>,
                        "<?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?>",
                        "<?php echo $_SESSION['acc_type']; ?>",
                        "<?php echo $_SESSION['lang']; ?>",
                        "<?php echo $_SESSION['first_name']; ?>",
                        "<?php echo $_SESSION['last_name']; ?>",
                        "<?php echo $_SESSION['picture']; ?>",
                        "<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>"
                        );
            });
```

And i created another javascript file say myweb.js
code is like this

```
var _no_profile_pic = "../img/no_profile_pic.png";

/* 
 * Class    :   $portal.user
 * Desc     :   Portal User Related Functions
 */
$portal.user = {
    user_id: 0,
    user_name: '',
    acc_type: '',
    lang: '',
    first_name: '',
    last_name: '',
    picture: '',
    email: '',
    /*
     * $portal.user.init : Initilise user
     * Params   :
     *      user_id - user id
     *      user_name - login user name
     *      acc_type - Type of user account like (A - Admin, V - Verified, U - Unverified, D - Deleted)
     *      lang - User Language like (en-english)
     *      first_name - User First Name
     *      last_name - User Last Name
     *      picture - User Picture URL
     *      email - User Email Address
     * Returns  : None
     */
    init: function(user_id, user_name, acc_type, lang, first_name, last_name, picture, email)
    {
        $portal.user.user_id = user_id;
        $portal.user.user_name = user_name;
        $portal.user.acc_type = acc_type;
        $portal.user.lang = lang;
        $portal.user.first_name = first_name;
        $portal.user.last_name = last_name;
        $portal.user.picture = (picture == indef || picture == '' ? _no_profile_pic : picture);
        $portal.user.email = email;
        alert(this.user_id);
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you check your console for any errors and also whether jquery lib is loaded  ?

Comment: Whats `indef`? -> `picture == indef` - For undefined or empty you can `.picture = picture || _no_profile_pic,` (That glob is probably better put within the class as well)

Comment: it gives error in console - ReferenceError: $portal is not defined
 

$portal.user = {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first define `$portal` as an object, before you try to set its properties by adding the user object.

```
$portal = {}; // define $portal as an object

// now the user object can be added
$portal.user = {
    ...
    ...
};
```

Comment: Great @MrCode, you are great...thank you so much form your help.